# jQuery setting text inside of a [object Text] item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a translation function inside for my web application, I can select the item with code and print it to the console.  Inside the console, I can right click and click "Edit text" and it works fine and sets it.  Moreover, when I try and set it in code using the jQuery function `.text()`, it does not work.  The object I am trying to select and change is like this `<div>Hello <strong>world</strong></div>`, where `hello` is what I am trying to select and change.

The code that is trying to set it is here.

```js
if (child.toString() == '[object Text]') {
    let lengthOfChars = $(child).text().split(' ').join('').split('\n').join('').split('\t').join('').length;
    if (lengthOfChars > 0) {
        if (langSet[$(child).text()]) {
            let newText = langSet[$(child).text()];
            $(child).text(newText);

            console.log(child);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives out the selected item of which I can change by right clicking, I just cannot change it programmatically as of yet.

[image]

Comment: Instead of `child.toString() == '[object Text]'`, please use `child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`. It seems jQuery can’t really be used for Text nodes. Use `child.textContent = newText;` instead.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the heads up.  At the time of writing that, I didn't know the how to check that.

Also thanks so much, it would seem you were correct with the child.textContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Sebastian Simon, the way to set these types cannot be set using jQuery but rather using `child.textContent`